# Can an induced EMF be generated from a loop kept in an constant electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

I am wondering whether the following set-up can be used to generate an induced EMF.

[image]

Since the electric field between the parallel-plates is in such a direction that the positive charge accumulate at the upper end and negative charge accumulate at the lower end, thus creating a potential difference between them and so the loop should have an induced current.

But I also read that **no electrostatic field can generate an EMF or induced EMF**.
Mathematically it said,
$$ V_{emf} = \int \vec{E}.d\vec{l} = \int_S (\nabla  \times \vec{E}) . d\vec{a} = 0$$
Since $(\nabla  \times \vec{E}) = 0 $

So how and where is my set-up wrong?

Note that it's **Electric field** here and you can ignore end effects or fringing effect.
I know that in a uniform magnetic field, the loop when moved perpendicularly with a velocity $v$, can cause an induced EMF. I just want to know can this setup also cause an induced emf and if not, why so?